# React routing following path of one previous defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my routing i have an Route with the path `/:username/opinions` and i want to add `/:username/opinions/new` but i register it and the page is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Always put more specific routes on top i.e. `/:username/opinions/new` before `/:username/opinions/`. Also you should use the `exact` prop on `/:username/opinions`